# como eu mudo o cor de fundo usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

eu tentei esse code mas não foi. Eu sou iniciante e quem poder estiver disponível para tirar outras duvidas eu vou ficar muito grato.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementbById(fundo).style.backgroundColor = "black";
</script>
</head>

<body id="fundo">
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Seu código está quase correto. O problema é que você escreveu o nome do método `getElementById` de forma errada e esqueceu as aspas no ID. O código deveria ser:

```
document.getElementById("fundo").style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

Segue um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("fundo").style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

```css
/* estilo apenas para o texto aparecer quando mudar a cor de fundo */
#fundo {
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="fundo">
  Fundo
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael Silva você pode usar:

document.querySelector('#fundo');

Segue o eexemplo:

```
OnClick('#Fundo')=function()
{
       document.querySelector('#fundo');
}
```